# Multiple Calculation Loops interfere with each other

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to figure out why two calculation loops in my Excel project are interfering with each other and how to separate them.

The `outputValueF39` of the first calculation is writing in the cells from the second calculation

```
Set calcRangeAll = Sheets("Kalkulation Final").Range("F16:M83")
```

(minus the skipped rows) which shouldn't happen, it should only write in the

```
Set calcRangeF16F19 = Sheets("Kalkulation Final").Range("F16:F19")
```

range.

```
' Output the value to the corresponding cells from F16 to F19 in the "Kalkulation Final" worksheet
        Dim calcRangeF16F19 As Range
        Set calcRangeF16F19 = Sheets("Kalkulation Final").Range("F16:F19")
        
        For Each cell In calcRangeF16F19
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                ' Check if the cell already contains a numeric value
                ' If yes, calculate the average between the existing value and the new value and round it to 2 decimal places
                cell.Value = Round((cell.Value + outputValueF39) / 2, 2)
            Else
                cell.Value = outputValueF39 ' Write the value to the cell
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Output the value to the corresponding cells from F16 to F19 in the "Kalkulation Final" worksheet
        Dim calcRangeAll As Range
        Set calcRangeAll = Sheets("Kalkulation Final").Range("F16:M83")
        
        For Each cell In calcRangeAll
            If cell.Row = 20 Or cell.Row = 27 Or cell.Row = 33 Or cell.Row = 38 Or cell.Row = 50 Or cell.Row = 57 Or cell.Row = 64 Or cell.Row = 68 Or cell.Row = 69 Or cell.Row = 70 Or cell.Row = 71 Or cell.Row = 72 Or cell.Row = 79 Or cell.Row = 83 Then
                ' Check if the cell is in the skipped rows
                ' If yes, jump to the next iteration
                GoTo SkipCell
            End If
            
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                ' Check if the cell already contains a numeric value
                ' If yes, calculate the average between the existing value and the new value and round it to 2 decimal places
                cell.Value = Round((cell.Value + outputValueF11) / 2, 2)
            Else
                cell.Value = outputValueF11 ' Write the value to the cell
            End If
    
SkipCell:
Next cell
```

I tried separating the loops through different terms, like `Exit For`, but doing that stops the loops completely.

Comment: F16:M83 includes F16:F19 so it's fairly clear your second loop may overwrite the first loop's cells?

Comment: It should ONLY overwrite the F16:F19 cells, but it writes in ALL the F16:M83 cells, excluding the skipped ones.

Comment: `IsNumeric(cell.Value)` will return True for an empty cell (because the default value for an empty cell is zero), so also check that `Len(Cell.Vaue) >0`

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixed a calculation error, that was a bit lower priority.
Do you have an idea on how to separate the loops or what I could try in general?

Comment: You have two separate Loops. The first For Each cell In calcRangeF16F19 checks only 4 cells. The second For Each cell In calcRangeAll checks 544 cells (Range("F16:M83")). It excludes 14 rows (20, 27, 33, 38, 50, 57, 64, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 79, 83) that each have 8 cells, so it excludes (14 * 8 = 112) cells . Modifies the remaining (544 - 112 = 432) cells. What do you want to do after all?  I don't think you have explained clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

When testing for numeric values it's also a good idea to check the cell isn't empty.

eg:

```vb
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range
    '...
    '...
    Set ws = Sheets("Kalkulation Final")
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("F16:F19")
        cell.Value = IIf(HasNumber(cell), Round((cell.Value + outputValueF39) / 2, 2), outputValueF39)
    Next cell
    
    For Each cell In ws.Range("F16:M83").Cells
        'skip already-processed cells
        If Application.Intersect(cell, ws.Range("F16:F19")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case cell.row
                Case 20, 27, 33, 38, 50, 57, 64, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 79, 83
                Case Else
                    cell.Value = IIf(HasNumber(cell), Round((cell.Value + outputValueF11) / 2, 2), outputValueF11)
            End Select
        End If
    Next cell
```

Helper function:

```
'is cell value no-zero length and numeric?
Function HasNumber(c As Range) As Boolean
    Dim v
    v = c.Value
    HasNumber = Len(v) > 0 And IsNumeric(v)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Tim, greatly appreciated.

I think I haven't made myself clear enough on my intentions.

My goal is to fully cover all cells of the table through the calcRangeAll, which should put a value depending on a dropdown menu from another sheet into all the table cells, while skipping some.

I need additional functions/loops to alter specific cell values.
Thats what calcRangeF16F19 is used for.

In general, if a cell already has a value >0, the new value should be added and the sum should be divided through 2. If the cell is empty, just write the value into the cell.

Comment: The `Intersect` check will skip F16:F19 in the loop over F16:M83, or you can instead loop over `Range("G16:M19,F20:M83").Cells`, which already excludes F16:F19

Comment: The calcRangeF16F19  is supposed to alter the cells F16:F19 in the same table where calcRangeAll already put in values. 

Thats all working as intended.

The problem is, that the calcRangeF16F19 doesnt stop at F16:F19, but instead covers the whole calcRangeAll cells "F16:M83" with the exception of the ones skipped. It should only alter the cells F16:F19, but for whatever reason, my loops aren't separated.

Comment: I can't see how that could happen given the code you posted. `Range("F16:F19")` only covers those 4 cells.   There's something I'm not getting in how you're explaining this.  If the second loop in your posted code is not relevant then maybe remove that part?  Maybe `outputValueF11` doesn't have the value you expect?